# Stata regression to find out treatment effect

Tags: regression, stata

I want to run a regression to find out which effect my treatment, open goal setting, had on the step count made.

I have the following variables:

- *before* (average of the steps before the treatment/goal setting)
- *after* (average of the steps after the treatment/goal setting)
- *treatment* (dummy variable that is = 1 if the person openly set there goal and = 0 if the person did not openly set their goal)

Usually, if I would have time series data with all step counts together (e.g. called "step count" I would use the command "reg step count treatment", however since I have this data divided into two variables I am not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a reshape, changing your data from wide to long, which will put the data in the format you're more used to. See `help reshape`.

Answer (score 0):

If your data consist of 4 variables: id, treatment, before, after. The following code should reshape (as pointed out in the previous answer) your data to your desired format (the treatment variable would expand accordingly).

```
* reshape the data from wide to long
rename (before after) (steps1 steps2)
reshape long steps, i(id) j(time)
```